# An interesting definition of a structure-preserving map inspired by natural transformation

Tags: category-theory

The book "Conceptual mathematics..." (Lawvere and Schanuel, 1997) introduces the category of "sets with endomaps" (that resemble a set theoretic representation of monoids). Then the book proceeds to give the definition of a "structure-preserving maps" between those structures that conceptually resemble functors. However, the definition of this map is actually quite different from the traditional functor definition and is actually closer to the definition of natural transformation (see the screenshot.)

Later the book also reviews the category of (set-theoretic representations of) graphs and the definition of maps between them is similar.

I was wondering what is the formal definition of such structure-preserving maps would be and if they are defined anywhere else.

[image: Lawvere and Schanuel, 1997 - page 152]

Comment: A set with endomap is a functor from $\mathbb{N}$ regarded as a 1-object category to $\mathbb{Set}$, and the morphisms of these "sets with endomap" are then just natural transformations of functors.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. And there are probably ways to encode many different structures in a similar way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many versions in many abstraction levels of 'structure preserving maps'.

A 'set with endomap' in universal algebraic language is called a '*unary algebra*': it is a set $X$ with a single unary operation $\alpha:X\to X$.
Further universal algebraic structures might have multiple finitary operations (an $n$-ary operation is simply a map $X^n\to X$).

Further, there are first order structures. Those themselves have multiple notions of 'structure preserving maps' because of the presence of relations.

A category theoretic approach is as follows:

Consider an endofunctor $T:\mathcal S\to\mathcal S$ on a category $\mathcal S$ (which is typically $\mathcal{Set}$).
Then a *$T$-algebra* is a pair $(x,\alpha)$ where $x\in Ob\,\mathcal S$ and $\alpha:T(x)\to x$.

A structure preserving map from $(x,\alpha)$ to $(y,\beta)$ is an arrow $f:x\to y$ in $\mathcal S$ which satisfies $\beta\circ T(f)=f\circ\alpha$.

Often, $T$ is assumed to be a [monad](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory)) and then the algebra structure also needs to be compatible with the monad structure (see section 'algebras over a monad').

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. A couple of follow ups if you have time (I can probably pick them up with the leads you gave me, but in this way the answer would be more complete): 1) Can you elaborate on how the category of sets with endomap gives rise to a T-algebra e.g. what is x and what is \alpha here? and 2) "Further, there are first order structures..." can you elaborate on that. Thanks again.

Comment: 1. For endomaps (unary algebras) $T={\rm id}_{\mathcal Set}$ and thus $\alpha:X\to X$ is the endomap (the unary operation). If we have a single binary operation, then $T(X)=X\times X=X^2$. If we have more $n_i$-ary operations then $T(X)=\sqcup_i X^{n_i}$ is the disjoint union of self powers of $X$. 2) If you're interested, look up first order models. It's not fully necessarily though to get a broader picture.